# Backbone.js - Collection request event not firing

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have the following challenge:

I want to implement a loading flower every time I fetch data.

My **bootstrapping code** looks like this:

```
var myCollection = new MyCollection({});
myCollection.fetch({
        success: function () {
            var listView = new ListView({model: myCollection});
        }
});
```

My **view** looks like this:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('request', this.ajaxStart, this);
        this.model.bind('sync', this.ajaxComplete, this);
        self.render();
    },
});
```

My problem: The `request` event is not fired because at the time, the request starts, the `ListView` is not set up yet.

I tried to change my bootstrapping code but nothing works so far. It's always a `chicken or the egg` problem. Either I have the view set up at the right place or I have the data.

I tried to pass the `collection` instance to the view but this seems to be not possible via a `set()` or another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should reorganize your structure, setting collection as a view model is not very obvious. Maybe you should add ListModel, that will handle your collection instantiating and updating, and then set your view to listen to your ListModel custom events. As for the chicken / egg problem

```
var myCollection = new MyCollection();
var myView = new MyView({
  collection: myCollection,
});

myCollection.fetch();

// inside your view
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your input. Works! Still a little hard for me to get the correct structure of backbone for me. There are just too many ways to do things :)

Comment: That's the point of Backbone, it gives you all the control, but the other side of this is sometimes you have too many options). But it gets better the more you use it. Also, consider reading Backbone fundamentals by Addy Osmani https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/